# C# NHibernate Simple Question

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using `NHibernate`-driven repository, `Fluent` mappings and attempt to use `Linq to NHibernate`.

*But for some simple query like this*

```
Retrieve<XValue>(x => (x.Timestamp.CompareTo(start) >= 0 &&
                       x.Timestamp.CompareTo(end) <= 0 ));

// 'Retrieve' here acts simply as 'session.Query<T>().Where(expression);'
```

*I get the following result:*

```
System.NotSupportedException: Int32 CompareTo(System.DateTime)
```

I don't know why, but `CompareTo` operations aren't projected to the database and the output is also kind of weird:

```
create table "QuotUnitDescriptor" (
    Id  integer,
   PaperId INTEGER,
   Timestamp DATETIME,
   InPaperIdx INTEGER,
   primary key (Id)
)

NHibernate: INSERT INTO "QuotUnitDescriptor" ......................

// Many INSERT's

NHibernate: select cast(count(*) as INTEGER) as col_0_0_ 
    from "QuotUnitDescriptor" binaryunit0_
```

I can't understand why this operation invokes a `select -> integer` operation.

**How should the following date-oriented query be implemented?** *(using `Linq` is better, but criterias are also fine, I think).*

Comment: You're comparing your timestamp to 0. Maybe that's why?

Comment: @Yads I'm comparing it to `start` and `end` timestamps in my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

NHibernate.Linq provider is unable to transform `CompareTo` call to sql.

Use something like:

```
Retrieve<XValue>(x => x.Timestamp>start && x.Timestamp<end);
```

P.s. and avoid repositories. That's a naive abstraction.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please comment your statement about repositories. What kind of abstractions should I use instead them? Those, which are more domain-specific?

Comment: @Yippie-Kai-Yay if You are using NHibernate, don't try to abstract it away. Make sure You want to tie Yourself with it and once You do - live w/ that. It seems fine (usage of repositories) only until You start facing deeper object graphs and performance issues. It's more beneficial to ensure You have rich domain model which validates state changes properly than to try abstracting away boring `read` side of Your app. http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2011/03/16/architecting-in-the-pit-of-doom-the-evils-of-the.aspx