# How do compare strings with nhibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm trying to do something like:

```
Session.Query<VoiceMailNumber>()
            .Where(x => (x.From.CompareTo(number) > 0) &&
                  (x.To.CompareTo(number)) > 0)
```

But that throws System.NotSupportedException.

From and number are both strings.

Any solution?

Comment: Define "doesn't work", does it throw the fabled `DoesntWorkException`, what does it do?

Comment: No. System.NotSupportedException

Comment: IMHO nhibernate cant "translate CompareTo() function to sql statement" so try `x.From == number`

Comment: Similar problem [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5383470/754438)

Comment: Thanks, but that solution just says: Don't use compareTo. But how do I then compare strings? I can't just write .Where(x => x.From > number)  (Doesn't compile)

Comment: Found a solution :-)  Using CreateCriteria instead of query

Comment: 4 more information from [here caution section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/35f0x18w.aspx): `The CompareTo method was designed primarily for use in sorting or alphabetizing operations. It should not be used when the primary purpose of the method call is to determine whether two strings are equivalent. To determine whether two strings are equivalent, call the Equals method.`. So in general you using inappropriate function to compare strings.

Comment: @Reniuz, the OP's code isn't testing for equality.  It's testing for alphabetical sorting.  Nowhere has the OP said he's looking for string equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solves it:

```
Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(VoiceMailNumber))
                .Add(Expression.Le("From", number))
                .Add(Expression.Ge("To", number))
                .UniqueResult<VoiceMailNumber>();
```

I'm not super happy with this solution, but since it's not possible to compare strings using query or queryover, it will have to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare string exactly using this syntax:

```
Session.Query<VoiceMailNumber>()
  .Where(x => x.From==number)
  .And(x=>x.To==number);
```

Translates to:

```
select * from VoiceMailNumber where From='123456' and To='123456'
```

Comment: Yeah. But I don't want to check if they are equal.

Comment: What SQL function do you want to use for the comparison?